# How to delete temporary User account in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, organizational-unit

I have created a script to create user accounts under AWS Organizations.

Now,I am trying to automate deleting temporary user accounts in 30Min?

What could be the possible solutions? I can work on RESTAPIs, Lambda, CloudFormation.

Manual process is there but I am trying to give kind off trial access to users for 30Min

Comment: Please clarify: are you creating a new AWS account for each trial and it is those AWS accounts you want to delete?

Comment: exactly, some secured and automated solution i need

Answer (score 1):

You can invoke Lambda with Cloudwatch logs.

As such, you could trigger an AWS Lambda function to remove the user 30 minutes after activity from that user is detected in the Cloudwatch logs (eg the creation of a resource).

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-cloudwatchlogs.html

If it were not possible to identify a user action in Cloudwatch, you could chain IAM -> Cloudtrail -> S3 -> Lambda to invoke the deletion routine. This would involve a bit more effort, in that your Lambda function would need to be able to read the Cloudtrail log and identify the user.

Comment: I am not sure on how to create such lambda function, do you have any example

Answer (score 0):

AWS does not provide an API to close an AWS account.

The only way to close an account is through the web user interface.

To achieve what you want, the closest thing would be to keep a pool of empty accounts available. Use one when needed. When done, use the APIs to empty out the account and return it to the pool.

**Personal Anecdote**

In my experience, closing an account was even more complicated than that. In order to close an account opened under an organization, I needed to do the following:

1. Remove the AWS account from the organization.
2. Provide a credit card number to the account.
3. Close the account.

**References:**

- [Closing an Account](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/close-account.html)